# LocalStorage doesn't stay updated on page refresh in MERN Application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

LocalStorage somehow doesn't want to stay updated on refresh page. I'm not sure why is that happening, and where is my mistake. The backend is updating fine but the localStorage doesn't stay updated.

Here is where I'm updating localStorage:

```
    const UserContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({})
    const [cart, setCart] = useState(localStorage.getItem("cart") || [])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`${API}/auth/user`, {
            method: 'GET',
            withCredentials: true,
            credentials: 'include'
        })
        .then (response => response.json())
        .then (response => {
            setUser(response.user)
        })
        .catch (error => {
            console.error (error);
        });
    }, [setUser])
    

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(user.cart))
    }, [setUser])

    const addToCart = (user, product) => {
        fetch(`${API}/cart/usercart`, {
            method:"POST",
            headers: { 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        body: JSON.stringify([user._id, product])
        })
        .then(() => setUser({...user, cart: [...user.cart, product]}))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }

    return (
        <UserProvider value={[user, setUser, addToCart, cart]}>
            {props.children}
        </UserProvider>
    )
}   

export default UserContextProvider;
```

And here is the component where I'm trying to use it:

```
const Cart = props => {
    
    const [user, setUser, cart] = useContext(UserContext)  

...

{cart?.length === 0 ? <></> :
                <>
                {cart?.map(product => {
                    return(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code only runs once when the component mounts:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setCart(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart")) || [])
}, []);
```

In order to render the latest value you'll have to depend on a prop or something that updates when cart updates:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setCart(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart")) || [])
}, [props.something]);
```

Based on your implementation, I'd recommend having your contextProvider provide this data instead of component itself retrieving it from localStorage on each render. You only need the localStorage value when the app starts.

Comment: But it should work on a page refresh, shouldn't it?

Comment: But it doesn't now even save the data in localStorage

Comment: I put in the useEffect dependency array "setUser", cuz I'm changing it when I add a product in the function down. But now the local storage stays empty, and I can't map the cart in Cart component as before

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-ellis-2pyv5?file=/src/globalParams.js

Comment: @hendra you can check it. I add the whole Contextand Cart components.

Comment: @Yollo in the problems tab next to console you can see potential problems

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-ellis-2pyv5?file=/src/globalParams.js @hendra

Comment: I saw it, now other warns are just for those that are declared but not used

Comment: And again, I cant setCart in localstorage